# How do you define sequence_separator for FriendlyId 5.0.4 on Rails 4.1.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Using friendly_id 5.0.4 with Rails 4.1.4.

Somehow, when adding `config.sequence_separator = '_'` to `config/initializers/friendly_id.rb`, I get this following fatal error which prevents Rails from starting:

```
config/initializers/friendly_id.rb:60:in `block in <top (required)>':  undefined method `sequence_separator=' for #<#<Class:0x007fefb9b6b010>:0x007fefb9b6aac0> (NoMethodError)
```

When I tried to set it directly in my model, it has no effect, and uses the default hyphen instead:

```
friendly_id :name, use: [ :slugged, :finders ], slug_column: :username, sequence_separator: '_'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Looking at this spec](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/5.0-stable/test/slugged_test.rb#L15) the latter should work. Are you sure you restarted the server, etc?

Comment: It doesn't work on Rails 4.1 and with FriendlyId 5.1 (latest stable). It seems that this is a bug in the default initialiser code or a missing attr_writer in base modules, I'll create an issue on github